# Check to see if user actually payed for in-app purchase [iOS, Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, icloud

Here is a strange one for you :)

I have an iOS app that has a non-consumable product as a in-app purchase that the users could buy. It's kind of a lifetime subscription if you'd like.

The thing is that i had a bug in my code which allowed users to "subscribe" to my app by tapping on Restore Purchases button.

I fixed the bug now but i have a problem. Roughly 50 users are now subscribed but never payed for this service.

Is there a way to see if the user actually payed for this somehow? I would like to unsubscribe them if they did not pay.

The system works this way:

The user taps on Purchase, Apple takes care of the purchase for me and when processing the payment queue, if the purchase was a success i subscribe the user by adding their iCloud ID to my database. So the only piece of data that i have is their iCloud id and nothing else. I don't know which iCloud ID is a "payed" one and which is "cheating" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the receipt from the user's device and check with Apple's endpoint to see if the user has a valid purchase. Ideally you should take the receipt from the app and send it to your server to perform the verification in your backend.

Check this documentation to obtain receipt from the device - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store

Check this documentation to call verify the receipt with Apple's endpoint - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!

I actually tried this in the sandbox environment with strange results.

I tried it with my account (which is a payed user on sandbox) and the code to get the receipt on the phone didn't find a receipt.
Then i tried to get the receipt from apple's servers and it got the receipt.

But then when trying with a non-paying newly created user, it also found a receipt for him.

Can you explain a little bit how this works? I cannot find anything on the web for it.

Comment: Try to make a purchase on the app and then check if the receipt exists. I've never faced this situation, does indeed sound weird.

Regarding the receipt for a non-paying user - from my experience all users have a base64 encoded receipt. But if you pass that receipt to the `verifyReceipt` API, it will return all the purchases. This is why I mentioned you should check with the Apple's endpoint with the base64 receipt. You can't determine if a user has made a purchase just by checking if the user has a base64 encoded receipt on the phone.

Comment: There you go, that's it! I didn't check it with Apple, i was assuming that if there is a receipt, then there is a purchase. Apple docs are really inefficient. Thank you good sir!